# Block navigation in Silverlight Webbrowser Control

Tags: silverlight-4.0

From a Silverlight Out-of-browser application using the Webbrowser control, I need a way to prevent navigating to selected URL’s.

With no navigating events exposed I don’t see any way to block the navigation. Anyone know of a work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser control has a loaded and load complted event that may offer a chance to restrict the navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping to prevent the page from loading, but it looks like I'll need to redirect on the load completed events.